# Retrieve authenticated user's info from Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't seem to get any information about the logged in user for my website e.g. the alert in my example just says "undefined" instead of the name. I don't know what I'm doing wrong as I'm following the sample code to the letter.

This is from the `<body>` of the page.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId      : 'blahblah',
                    status     : true, 
                    cookie     : true,
                    xfbml      : true,
                    oauth      : true
                });

                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    alert(response.name);
                });
            };
            (function(d){
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
            }(document));
        </script>
        <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

I can log in but the alert never says my name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the running of your code you will want to first check FB.getLoginStatus

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Then your code might looks something like:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

         FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            alert(response.name);
         });
    } else {
        FB.login( see documentation for FB.login );
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The FB.api call is happening after the FB.init call. It's not tied in any way to the login button so it's being called before you're logged in. If you want that to happen on click, you need to modify the code so that it doesn't try to execute until after you've logged in.

Try changing your code to this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      alert(response.name);
   });
});
```